# starting openvpn server fails with Options error: --client-config-dir fails

Tags: debian, openvpn

I'm working on setting up an openvpn server. I'm using the standard sources of debian jessie and easy-rsa as an CA.

Everything worked fine until I've tried to start openvpn via init script. When I'm running `/etc/init.d/openvpn start`
following error comes up in /var/log/daemon.log

```
Options error: --client-config-dir fails with "/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/crl.jail//etc/openvpn/server.ccd": No such file or directory
```

Has someone of you a idea where this mess with the paths comes from? 
The directory what is set in the config file exists.
The server.conf file:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun

comp-lzo
keepalive 10 120

persist-key
persist-tun
user nobody
group nogroup

chroot /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/crl.jail
crl-verify crl.pem

ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ca.crt
dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/dh2048.pem
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ta.key 0
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server.key
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server.crt

ifconfig-pool-persist /var/lib/openvpn/server.ipp
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/server.ccd
status /var/log/openvpn/server.log
verb 4

# virtual subnet unique for openvpn to draw client addresses from
# the server will be configured with x.x.x.1
# important: must not be used on your network
server 10.254.1.0 255.255.255.0

# push routes to clients to allow them to reach private subnets
push "route 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0"
```

THX for your help.

Comment: Copy the script `cp -r /usr/share/easy-rsa/ /etc/openvpn` then restart the service `/etc/init.d/openvpn restart`

Comment: The easy-rsa folder is at place. I've allready used easy-rsa to generate certificates.

Answer (score 1):

I found the bug. The server.ccd has to be in the crl.jail directory. I've changed the config like this:

```
...
chroot /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/crl.jail
crl-verify crl.pem

ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ca.crt
dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/dh2048.pem
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ta.key 0
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server.key
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server.crt

ifconfig-pool-persist /var/lib/openvpn/server.ipp
client-config-dir server.ccd

...
```